# python django randomly select value excluding one

Tags: python, django, random

I have a view like:

```
winner = random.choice(player_list)

try:
    check_winner = Winner.objects.get(phone_no=9899889988)
    if check_winer:
        winner = random.choice(player_list)
    else:
        winner = winner
except Winner.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Here what I want is if check_winner exists then again randomly select the winner from player but excluding that check_winner

How can I exclude some value from random list of players

Answer (score 0):

Choose a random number in [0, len(player_list)-2]. If the number is >= player_list.index(check_winner) then increment it's value by one. That is:

```
rand_player = random.randint(0, len(player_list) - 2)
if(player_list.index(check_winner) <= rand_player):
    rand_player+= 1
winner = player_list[rand_player]
```

Naturally, this is sorta bad as it's complexity is `O(n)`.

If you know the index if `check_winner` it will be constant.

The idea is, you are choosing randomly between all the other players, and simply jump-over the `check_winner` .